# ParDo function not waiting for Window in Apache BEAM

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've created a Window in Apache BEAM to wait either a window to expire or the window is too full (messages are unbounded and coming from a pub/sub queue):

```
   .apply("Window", Window.<TraceUpdateMessage>into(new GlobalWindows())
                        .withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.EARLIEST)
                        .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(
                                AfterFirst.of(
                                        AfterProcessingTime
                                                .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getFixedWindowDuration())),
                                        AfterPane
                                                .elementCountAtLeast(options.getFixedWindowElementCountTrigger())
                                )
                        ))
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                        .discardingFiredPanes()
                )
```

I've got a ParDo right after the window:

```
 .apply("Aggregate", ParDo.of(
                        new CustomAggregationFunction()
)
```

the problem is that the `CustomAggregationFunction` is getting called right away, and it doesn't look like the window is doing anything. The goal is go have the `CustomAggregationFunction` get called only when a Window is full and process all elements inside that window.

Answer (score 2):

Windowing doesn't take effect until any grouping transform. Inserting grouping transform such as group by key or reshuffle between `Window` and `ParDo` should work.